# A question on proving a midpoint when ratio of the area of triangles is given

Tags: geometry, contest-math

In a convex quadrilateral $PQRS$, the areas of triangles $PQS$, $QRS$ and $PQR$ are in the ratio $3 : 4 : 1$. A line through $Q$ cuts $PR$ at $A$ and $RS$ at $B$ such that $PA : PR = RB : RS$. Prove that $A$ is the midpoint of $PR$ and $B$ is the midpoint of $RS$.

This question appeared in a competitive mathematics exam. What I am doing is taking the ratios of the areas of triangles given and then equating this ratio to the respective sides of those triangles, like for example,

$PA : PR = RB : RS, \Rightarrow [PQA]:[PQR]=[QRB]:[QRS]$

Then, I am assuming that one of the things to be proved, $A$ is the midpoint of $PR$ (which I have proved implies that $B$ is the midpoint of $RS$), to be correct, and using this result, showing that these conditions comply with the assumption. But I am stuck at how to prove that these results comply for these assumption **exclusively**.

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using [barycentric coordinates](https://www.geogebra.org/m/c8DwbVTP) which is a way to work on ratios of areas. They are often useful in Mathematical Contests.

See the following picture.

[image]

*Fig. 1. a,b,c,d are areas delimited by diagonals.*

Without loss of generality, we can assume that the area of $PQRS$ is $1.$

Diagonals $PR$ and $QS$ define four (unsigned) areas denoted $a,b,c,d$.

The given ratios $3:4:1$ give the following relationships:

$$\begin{cases}a+b&=&3/7&(a)\\c+d&=&4/7&(b)\\b+c&=&1/7&(c)\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

Remark: combining (a)+(b)-(c), one gets:

$$a+d=6/7\tag{2}$$

Let us consider $PRS$ as the basis triangle, with barycentric coordinates of generic point $M$ given by quotients of *oriented* areas:

$$M=\begin{cases}p=area(MRS)/area(PRS)\\r=area(PMS)/area(PRS)\\  s=area(PRM)/area(PRS)\end{cases} $$

Using (1) and (2), it is easy to obtain the barycentric coordinates of :

$$Q=\begin{cases}
p_Q&=& \ \ \ (c+d)/(a+d)&=& \ \ \ 4/6\\
r_Q&=& \ \ \ (a+b)/(a+d)&=& \ \ \ 3/6\\
s_Q&=&-(b+c)/(a+d)&=&-1/6\end{cases}\tag{3}$$

Please note that the minus sign for $s_Q$ comes from the fact that *oriented* area$(PRQ)<0$.

Besides, if  $A$ and $B$ are *defined* as the midpoints of $PR$ and $SR$ resp., their barycentric coordinates are

$$A=\begin{cases}
p_A&=&1/2\\
r_A&=&1/2\\
s_A&=&0\end{cases}, \ \ \ \ \ 
B=\begin{cases}
p_B&=&0\\
r_B&=&1/2\\
s_B&=&1/2\end{cases}$$

As the determinant

$$\begin{vmatrix}p_A&p_B&p_Q\\
r_A&r_B&r_Q\\
s_A&s_B&s_Q
\end{vmatrix}=0$$

we conclude that $A,B,Q$ are aligned.

Edit: An even shorter way would have been, after (3), to use the fact that $r_Q=1/2$ to conclude that $Q$ belongs to the midline $AB$ whose barycentric equation is clearly $r=1/2$.

Comment: Very well explained, thanks a lot.

Comment: See the edit I just added.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

As we know the ratios of the areas of internal triangles, we have

$PO:OR = 3:4, QO:OS = 1:6$

We assume $OA = y, PO = 3x$.

Now applying Menelaus's theorem in $\triangle SOR$ where line $BQ$ cuts the triangle.

$\displaystyle \frac{SQ}{QO} \cdot  \frac{OA}{AR} \cdot \frac{RB}{BS} = 1$

$\displaystyle \frac{7y}{4x-y} = \frac{RS}{RB}-1 = \frac{PR}{PA}-1$

$\displaystyle \frac{7y}{4x-y} = \frac{7x}{3x+y}-1 = \frac{4x-y}{3x+y}$

$6y^2+29xy-16x^2 = 0 \implies (3y+16x) (2y-x) = 0$

That leads to $\displaystyle y = \frac{x}{2}$ and $\displaystyle PA = AR = \frac{7x}{2}$. As $A$ is midpoint of $PR$, so is $B$ the midpoint of $RS$.

Comment: "\displaystyle \frac{7y}{4x-y} = \frac{RS}{RB}-1 = \frac{PR}{PA}-1" Could you please elaborate on how this expression was derived?

Comment: $SO/OQ = 6 / 1$, so $ \ SQ / OQ = 7$. Also, $OA = y, AR = OR - OA = 4x - y$. We take $RB/BS$ to the other side so it is $BS/RB = (RS - RB) / RB = RS / RB - 1$. The question says $RS / RB = PR / PA$.

Comment: In the third expression, how did the term $\frac{7x}{3x+y}-1$ come? Is it the $\frac{RS}{RB}-1$ term? If yes, how are they both equal?

Comment: $\frac{RS}{RB} = \frac{PR}{PA}$, right? We assumed $PO = 3x$, so $OR = 4x$. So $PR = 7x$. $PA = PO + OA = 3x + y$.